# cpu usage is extremly high (1800%) due to mysql

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I am having a 4 GB vps box. At any time there are not more than 40 visitors browsing 10-15 page simultaneously. Suddenly 2 days back server cpu usage touching almost 2000%. Strange thing is when i stop the apache, it still does not go down. below is the top command result.

```
PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  CPU  MEM    TIME+ COMMAND
23644 mysql     15   0 12.7g 742m 6840 S 1812.0 18.1   1107:15 mysqld
14076 xyzaz  19   0  194m  16m 7348 S  7.1  0.4   0:00.22 php
14080 xyzaz  18   0  195m  17m 7276 S  6.5  0.4   0:00.20 php
```

i have troubleshooted every thing but no luck. I dont know it was working fine but suddenly how it changed to such a high value.

below is the output of my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
max_connections=500
key_buffer_size=128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
join_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=2M
max_heap_table_size=16M
table_cache=1800
thread_cache_size=384
interactive_timeout=25
wait_timeout=7200
connect_timeout=10
max_allowed_packet=268435456
max_connect_errors=100
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_type=1
tmp_table_size=64M
skip-name-resolve

innodb_buffer_pool_size=229M
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 6553

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=16M
[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M
```

Any help is really appriciated

Comment: you probably have a query running that is taking forever to complete. You should look on the sql side

Comment: It is slow queries and/or lack of indexes.  Set `long_query_time=1`; turn on slowlog; wait a day; run `pt-query-digest` to find worst couple of queries; show them to us (together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`); we'll tell you what to fix.